# Anaconda change 'base' environment permanently to a different environment 'myenv' to startup at terminal openings

Tags: command-line, bash, python, python3, anaconda

I would like to change the `base` install environment that initiates when I start a terminal to a different environment that I have created called `myenv` anaconda environment.

I want `myenv` to start every time I start the terminal.

I have turned off the `base` environment from initiating.

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

In my `.bashrc` file I already have a `conda` init at the end. I am not sure if I should anything with it.

```bsh
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/nul>
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/MYUSERNAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: Would `conda activate myenv` in your `~/.bashrc` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following line at the end of it:

```
conda activate myenv
```

You can also add it using this command:

```
echo "conda activate myenv" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Don't comment out or remove the `conda` initialization block. Just put the `conda` command at the end of your `.bashrc`.

The content of `~/.bashrc` is run every time you start a terminal, so adding the `conda` command activates your `myenv` environment when opening a new terminal.